# replace nested 'for loop' with lambda in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on one task where I need to check the cosine similarity between two dataframe columns.
I am using two for loop to iterate over two columns of data1 and data2 respectively.

```
for i in range(0,len(input_df)): 
    for j in range(0,len(data1)):
        ##check similarity ratio
        similarity_score= cosine_sim(input_df['Summary'].iloc[i],data1['Summary'].iloc[j])
        print(similarity_score)

###cosine_sim() is my function that gave similarity score.
```

how can i do this using `Lambda` instead of `for loop` as nested loop is taking much time.
There are other operations as well which I am doing after checking the cosine similarity.

Comment: Your code is slow because you have O(n^2) values to compute, not because you are using nested loops. Anything you do is going to take O(n^2) time.

Comment: Could you give us an example of your dataframe and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To compute the cosine similarity between two vectors (your two columns), you could make use of NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))

cosine_similarity(input_df['Summary'], data1['Summary'])
```

However, based on your code example, it seems that you want to compute the cosine similarity between each element of the columns. So I'm not entirely sure if the above is what you are looking for.

Comment: @akensert- This will not help me however I have used `itertools- product` function to optimize the code to certain extent.